# Cannot find function SYS.FN_VARBINTOHEXSUBSTRIN on Windows Azure SQL DB

Tags: sql, azure

I have a problem migrating a SQL database to Windows Azure SQL database.

When I execute the script, I get the following message:

```
Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot find either column "SYS" or the user-defined function or aggregate 
"SYS.FN_VARBINTOHEXSUBSTRING", or the name is ambiguous.
```

Answer (score 0):

While Windows Azure SQL DB is SQL Server, all features available in your on-premise SQL Server are not available in Windows Azure SQL DB. I just explored my Windows SQL DB through SSMS and I could not find the above mentioned function there (see the screenshot below) whereas if I can see in my local SQL Express installation (under master database).

[image]

For a list of supported (and unsupported) functions, you may find this link useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336248.aspx.